# Get all values?

Tags: mysql

So let's say I've got a column named cash in my database. One user got 1000 in it and another got 150 in it. How do I put all these together? So I can show like how much cash all users got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean you just want to sum all the results for the column?

```
SELECT Sum(Cash) FROM YourTable
```

? If you want to sum the cash by user ID or something similar, you'll need a GROUP BY clause. See the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

use `SUM` and grouped them by user, example

```
SELECT user, SUM(cash)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY user
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have a table with the following data:

```
cash  | userName
1000    foo
150     bar
100     baz
200     baz
```

You can use `SUM` to sum up all rows. This query will return a single row with the value `1450`:

```
SELECT SUM(cash) AS totalCashForAllUsers
FROM myTable
```

---

If you want to show the sums for *each* user, you should `GROUP BY` the user. For example:

```
SELECT SUM(cash) AS totalCash, userName
FROM myTable
GROUP BY userName
```

This will give the following result:

```
totalCash  | userName
1000         foo
150          bar
300          baz
```